# How to keep filter keyword "active" on page reload

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to edit a js that filters data contained in a table. I've found the code below some years ago on the net and it still works perfectly. It's extremely light and more than enough for my needs.

Now I've added a script that makes the value entered into the text field is stored in local storage and is showed on page reload but... the filter is not active.

I'm not good at all with js and jQuery so is there anyone that can help me edit the js.table.filter script so that if a value is entered into the filter input text is stored and on page reload the filter is active so that on screen I see only the filtered results?

This is the js.table.filter

```js
(function(document) {
  'use strict';

  var TableFilter = (function(Arr) {

    var _input;

    function _onInputEvent(e) {
      _input = e.target;
      var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
      Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
        Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
          Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
        });
      });
    }

    function _filter(row) {
      var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(),
        val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
      row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    }

    return {
      init: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
        Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
          input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
        });
      }
    };
  })(Array.prototype);

  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      TableFilter.init();
    }
  });

})(document);
```

And this is the script that stores the value and adds it into the input box on page reload

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("filter").onkeyup = store;
    document.getElementById("filter").onload = getValue();
});


//store value after changes
function store(){
    var text = document.getElementById("filter").value;
    localStorage.setItem("filter",text);
}
//local storage to keep values after refresh
function getValue(){
    var storedText = localStorage.getItem("filter");
//    alert(storedText);
    if(storedText != null){
        document.getElementById("filter").value = storedText; 
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("filter").value = null;
}
```

The HTML code is just the following for the input

```html
<p>
  <input id="filter" type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="sub-table" placeholder="filter">
</p>
```

and then the table

```html
<table class="sub-table">
</table>
```

I'm not good with js so I haven't been able to try anything

Comment: Please post your HTML code as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering me. I've edited my post and addedd the couple lines of html code

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much JS; it's logic. Look at the code;

How does the table filter get going? `TableFilter.init()`. So just make sure your code for storing/loading from localStorage gets called after that.

I suggest moving the two lines you currently have in `DOMContentLoaded` under the `TableFilter.init()` line.

Looks like that filter script depends on the `input` event on the `filter` element (`input.oninput = _onInputEvent;`). That won't get called when you set the value programmatically (this part requires a bit of experience with the DOM), so trigger it manually after setting the value:

```
document.getElementById("filter").input();
```

Put altogether:

```js
(function(document) {
  'use strict';

  var TableFilter = (function(Arr) {

    var _input;

    function _onInputEvent(e) {
      _input = e.target;
      var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
      Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
        Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
          Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
        });
      });
    }

    function _filter(row) {
      var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(),
        val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
      row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    }

    return {
      init: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
        Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
          input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
        });
      }
    };
  })(Array.prototype);

  document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      TableFilter.init();
      document.getElementById("filter").onkeyup = store;
      document.getElementById("filter").onload = getValue();
    }
  });

})(document);

//store value after changes
function store() {
  var text = document.getElementById("filter").value;
  // TODO: Change back to localStorage
  localStore.setItem("filter", text);
}
//local storage to keep values after refresh
function getValue() {
  // TODO: Change back to localStorage
  var storedText = localStore.getItem("filter");
  //    alert(storedText);
  if (storedText != null) {
    document.getElementById("filter").value = storedText;
    document.getElementById("filter").input();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("filter").value = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://heretic-monkey.link/FauxStorage.js"></script>
<p>
  <input id="filter" type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="sub-table" placeholder="filter">
</p>
<table class="sub-table">
  <tr>
    <td>asd</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>qwer</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>asdf</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>qwerty</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm away from home for a couple days vacation but as soon as I go back I'll try it and will let you know.